# Pull file from Linux server

Tags: scp

I have `ssh` access to machine A, who has `ssh` access to machine B, but not the contrary

I know how to push a file from me to A

```bsh
scp file user@machineA:
```

But I don't know how to pull a file from B to A

The problem is that `scp user@machineB:file user@machineA:` can't work because I don't have access to machine B

The only solution I can think about would be like

```bsh
ssh user@machineA \
ssh user@machineB \
scp file user@machineA:
```

But that can't work because machine B doesn't have access to machine A

```bsh
ssh user@machineA \
scp user@machineB:file ./
```

For 5 levels that would be

```bsh
ssh user@machineA \
ssh user@machineB \
ssh user@machineC \
scp user@machineD:file ./

ssh user@machineA \
ssh user@machineB \
scp user@machineC:file ./

ssh user@machineA \
scp user@machineB:file ./

scp user@machineA:file ./
```

Isn't there a simpler solution?

I know there are many duplicates, but I don't understand those

Answer (score 0):

> The problem is that scp user@machineB:file user@machineA: can't work because machine B hasn't access to machine A

Not true. You're not running that command on machineB. The only thing needing access is the machine you're running `scp` on. Only when you specify `scp -R` would the origin host need to connect to the destination host.

Comment: From what I understood from `scp -v` is that `scp` connect to the first machine and from there push to the second machine. And in that case machine B wouldn't be able to push to machine A

Comment: but that's not correct.

Comment: So who connect to who, where the file does transit?

Comment: exactly as you wrote. Your statement "can't work" is plain wrong. It works. The file's contents are transferred from the origin host through your local machine to the target host.

Comment: B doesn't ever need to connect to A. I wrote that **three** times now.; please read my comment above again.

Comment: Oh, you edited your comment and I didn't see it. So I directly connect to machine A and B to push/pull from them. It will create a second problem for me because I only have access to machine A, not B, but A have access to B

Comment: You can use jump hosts with `-J`.

Comment: If I understand the manual well, it's exactly the same as my example, instead I have to write the intermediary steps into sshd_config instead of terminal